# Does CSS change the DOM?

Tags: css, dom

I was wondering if CSS changes the DOM.
The reason I am asking, is that whenever I change an Element with CSS, I don't see it's value changed in the "element".style properties.

Comment: No, it does not. The observation is correct/expected. Browser Developer tools will display the *computed stylesheet* values.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, whenever the DOM is rendered, it takes the stylesheet values as the default/ start values ?

Comment: In a way, yes - although explicit element style properties are more of “overrides” than “defaults”. Then CSS rendering engine takes _all_ stylesheet values (inline element styles, external stylesheets, and built-in browser default stylesheets), merges them together, and determines which rules to apply based on precedence. Individual element styles are more like “overrides” because only an !important can change these values. This is also why they are often better as a last-resort option.

Comment: These style sources are also “live” and any changes to them (as observed by the browser) will be reflected in rendering. In any case, the DOM still only _provides_ values.

Answer (score 3):

No, CSS does not change the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Actually... there are a few cases where CSS can *change the DOM*, but it's a bit far-stretched, as it won't change the DOM-tree structure, except in one yet even more far stretched case...

There is a [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#being-rendered) definition in the HTML specs that does impact the behavior of the DOM in some cases, based on CSS computed styles.

For instance,

- an *HTMLImageElement* can have its `width` and `height` IDL attributes value change [whether it is *being rendered* or not](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-img-element:being-rendered):

```js
onload = (evt) => {
  console.log( 'rendered', document.getElementById( 'disp' ).width );
  console.log( 'not rendered', document.getElementById( 'no-disp' ).width );
}
```

```css
img { width: 100px; } 
#no-disp { display: none; }
```

```html
<img id="disp" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png">
<img id="no-disp" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png">
```

- Elements that are not *being rendered* can not be *focusable elements*:

```js
document.getElementById( 'rendered' ).focus();
console.log( document.activeElement ); //  <input id="rendered">
document.getElementById( 'rendered' ).blur();

document.getElementById( 'not-rendered' ).focus();
console.log( document.activeElement ); //  <body>
```

```css
#not-rendered {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="rendered">
<input id="not-rendered">
```

And the one case where the DOM tree is modified, concerns the DOM tree of an inner Document: When an <object> or an <embed> element has its style set to `display:none`, [per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-object-element:nested-browsing-context-3), its inner Document should be reloaded:

> Whenever one of the following conditions occur
>
> [...]
>
> - the element changes from [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#being-rendered) to not being rendered, or vice versa,
>
> ...the user agent must queue an element task on the DOM manipulation task source given the object element to run the following steps to (re)determine what the object element represents.

So this means that simply switching the *being rendered* state of such an <object> or <embed> element is supposed to reload entirely its inner Document, which means also its DOM tree.

Now, only Safari behaves like that, Firefox never implemented that behavior, and [Chrome did recently change their](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=848283) to match FF's one, against the specs.
For Safari users, [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h08zob2/) demonstrating it.

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS does not change the DOM. 
Nor content injected using :after or :before alter the DOM.

Comment: I understand, very interesting. Than what does CSS change? and why doesn't it affect the DOM ?

Comment: @BenAshkenazi - CSS is combined with the HTML Document to form the render tree. DOM is an API for manipulating the HTML Document.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, whenever the DOM is rendered, it takes the stylesheet values as the default/ start values ?